# Why don't I have any JSON showing and a 403 message?

Tags: javascript, json, strapi

I completely new to Strapi. However, I have used Vue CLI many times before.

I am following this tutorial on how to use the two platforms together [https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-build-an-ecommerce-site-with-strapi-vue-js-and-flutterwave/][1].

After creating a list of products within Strapi, as in the tutorial, when I navigate to 'localhost:1337/products' I do not see any json being produced. Instead, I am presented with the following message:

```
{"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden"}
```

My Vue v-for loop reports that my data is undefined as a result.
Any help welcome.

Comment: You may find help at https://httpstatuses.com/403

Answer (score 0):

This had to do with Strapi Roles & Permissions. Once updated the data then worked.